# Why leading zeros from a numbers ignore on exporting polars dataframe to CSV?

Tags: python-polars

I have a polars dataframe with a number in a string datatype;

[image]

On exporting it to csv using write_csv method it ignores the leading zeros and the output it-

[image]

How to retain the zeros on exporting the files to csv?

Comment: Are you 100% positive that Excel not is trimming those zeros?

Comment: Above it looks like the number data is in the form of a String datatype. And below it looks like its been converted to integer or something else. write_csv does not do that on its own.

Comment: Open your csv file in a regular text editor, and see how it was exported by polars.

Comment: @TomNorway Yes, on text editor I can see as it it. i.e leading zeros are seen.

Comment: But is it quoted in the csv?

Answer (score 0):

Excel literally assumes numbers seeing those strings and promptly eliminates leading zeros (numbers are right-adjusted in Excel). Instead of saving the file with .csv extension pick .txt and open it in Excel. You should then be presented with the option (import dialogue) of choosing the column format, so pick "Text" and voilá.